# Is there a way to tell the compiler to ignore certain chunk of code in C?

Tags: c, cuda

I was writing a piece of code on C/CUDA which will give certain outputs based on the value selected by the user.
The user can edit this definition -- `#define WIDTH 128`
based on which the following code will be executed

```
/*              INTERNAL PROCESSING, IGNORE THIS SECTION                */
//Here we are initializing our datatype according to the width user entered and a random value which we will use to fill in our vectors
#if (WIDTH==8)
        typedef int8_t  dtype;
        dtype num = 4;
        #define isStruct 0
#elif (WIDTH==16)
        typedef int16_t dtype;
        dtype num = 4;
        #define isStruct 0
#elif (WIDTH==32)
        typedef int32_t dtype;
        dtype num = 4;
        #define isStruct 0
#elif (WIDTH==64)
        typedef int64_t dtype;
        dtype num = 4;
        #define isStruct 0
#elif (WIDTH==128)
        typedef struct dtype{
                int temp1;
                int temp2;
                int temp3;
                int temp4;
        }dtype;
        dtype num={4,4,4,4};
        #define isStruct 1
#endif
```

Later in the code I created a pointer and allocated some space using malloc which I filled with the value contained in 'num'

```
dtype *a_d;
a_d=(dtype *)malloc( some_size_I_chose);
for(....)
{
    a_d[i]=num;
}
```

At last, I just wanted to verify if things were going correctly as I planned so I wrote this verification loop -

```
               if(isStruct == 0)
                {
                        if( a_d[i] != num )
                        {
                                printf("Error Detected at position %d\n", i);
                                *dangerflag=1;
                        }
                }
                //FOR HANDLING STRUCTS FOR 128 BITS
                else if(isStruct == 1)
                {
                        if( (a_d[i].temp1 != num.temp1) && (a_d[i].temp2 != num.temp2) && (a_d[i].temp3 != num.temp3) && (a_d[i].temp4 != num.temp4))
                        {
                                printf("Error Detected at position %d\n", i);
                                *dangerflag=1;
                        }
                }
```

However, the compiler prints our an error if the user enters any value except 128

```
error: expression must have class type
```

Now I can make out that since # statements are preprocessing directives, the preprocessor defines the data types(not struct in case value defined by is not 128) due to which the compiler gets an error during compilation because the second chunk of code in my verification section involves struct related operations. One solution is to just define all other datatypes as structs also like this and make subsequent changes to the rest of the program -

```
#if (WIDTH==8)
        typedef struct dtype{
                int8_t  val;
                }dtype;
        dtype num = {4};
```

However I was wondering if I could tell the compiler not to compile certain code according to some condition. Is it possible?
Is there any other better way to get past this problem?

Comment: You can wrap the code in the same preprocessor macros to conditionally compile it.

Comment: Cuda is misnamed.  It is not `C/Cuda`, it is `C++/Cuda` (or, at least it was 7 years ago.  I can't imagine it's changed.)

Comment: `#if isStruct == 1`

Comment: Aside: Types not needed in allocation.  `a_d=(dtype *)malloc( some_size_I_chose);` --> `a_d = malloc( sizeof *a_d);` - at least in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However I was wondering if I could tell the compiler not to compile certain code according to some condition. Is it possible?

You have literally already done that.

```
#if (WIDTH==8)
    // this part is only compiled according to the condition (WIDTH==8)
        typedef int8_t  dtype;
        dtype num = 4;
        #define isStruct 0
#elif (WIDTH==16)
    // this part is only compiled according to the condition (WIDTH==16)
        typedef int16_t dtype;
        dtype num = 4;
        #define isStruct 0
#elif (WIDTH==32)
    // this part is only compiled according to the condition (WIDTH==32)
        typedef int32_t dtype;
        dtype num = 4;
        #define isStruct 0
#elif (WIDTH==64)
    // this part is only compiled according to the condition (WIDTH==64)
        typedef int64_t dtype;
        dtype num = 4;
        #define isStruct 0
#elif (WIDTH==128)
    // this part is only compiled according to the condition (WIDTH==128)
        typedef struct dtype{
                int temp1;
                int temp2;
                int temp3;
                int temp4;
        }dtype;
        dtype num={4,4,4,4};
        #define isStruct 1
#endif
```

Do it again.